# How to merge 2 collections of objects in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I got something like this

```php
 [
        {
            'id' : 1,
            'name' : 'Jhon'
            'age' : 18
        },
        {
            'id' : 2,
            'name' : 'Doe'
            'age' : 20
        },
    ]
```

and another collection with one different column

```php
    [
        {
            'id' : 1,
            'name' : 'Jhon'
            'status' : 0
        },
        {
            'id' : 2,
            'name' : 'Doe'
            'status' : 1
        },
    ]
```

and I want something like this

```php
    [
        {
            'id' : 1,
            'name' : 'Jhon',
            'age' : 18,
            'status' : 0
        },
        {
            'id' : 2,
            'name' : 'Doe',
            'age' : 20,
            'status' : 1
        },
    ]
```

I tried $collection1->merge($collection2) but I end up with just the values from $collection2

any idea how to do that?

Comment: You want to replace all variables with same id in first collection, if they contain in the second collection?

Comment: not replace but merge, so the objects in the collection that share the same Id will have both the attributes from the object in the first collection as in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) method on the collection will just merge the two collections of 2 elemenets into a single collection of 4 elements where it looks like you really want to merge the corresponding element of each collection.

The following should provide your desired output.

```php
$collectionA = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'age' => 18],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Doe', 'age' => 20],
]);

$collectionB = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'status' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Doe', 'status' => 1],
]);

$merged = $collectionA->map(function ($item) use ($collectionB) {
    return array_merge($item, $collectionB->where('id', $item['id'])->first());
});

dump($merged);
```